# Thar she Blows! Any info?

Tags: identify-this-game

[image]
Can someone please provide some info on the game? And possibly whay it may be worth? I have searched high and low and found nothing. All I really know is that the game is from the year 1939 and that all the pieces are here. Will provide more pictures. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the site! It will be a bit easier for everyone to help you out if you could add some more details about the game. [Check out the Tag info](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/tags/identify-this-game/info) for more information on what should be in your question to make it easier for people to help you out.

Comment: https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1851522/rare-trying-locate-any-information-old-1939-game-c

Comment: [Looks like there was a 1990 rerelease](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/8980/thar-she-blows/credits).